# Can Grapeseed oil be considered edible after it has passed the expiry date?

Tags: oil, spoilage

We have an un-opened bottle of grapeseed oil that got buried away and never used.
It has 'best by 3/31/2012' on the label.

Should I just throw it out or is it possibly still good? It's from Italy and a 'gold medal winner' so I'd prefer not to throw it out if I don't need to.

Is there any health risk of using it? Is there any use that would be better than others (eg do not use for salad dressing but still OK in skillet)?

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Your comment seems good enough to be an answer.

Comment: In the UK, if there were a health risk, it would say ‘Use by’ instead of ‘Best before’. (I'm guessing from the date format that the questioner was from the USA; I don't know if similar regulations apply there.)

Answer (score 5):

It has a decent glass bottle, and airtight cap? It wasn't in bright light for two years, and doesn't look like it has polymerized deposits or smell rancid? As a polyunsaturated oil, grape seed is susceptible to oxidation/polymerization/rancidity. If it hasn't done any of these things, by the evidence of your senses, it should still be OK.

-moved from comments